# Running JavaScript methods from Java in Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am writing application using PhoneGap on Android. I need to call some PhoneGap methods from native Java code. Anyone knows how to do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write your native code as an Android plugin (see an example here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner) then you have access to all of the PhoneGap Java classes and can call them as you like.